# React router animation getting unexpected token after browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition, single-page-application, react-router

I'm trying to implement `pages transitions animation` by `react-router`.
After I've compiled my code with `browserify/babel` I get '`unexpected token`' on this line: `static contextTypes = {` with the arrow pointing under the `=` sign.

I've copied/pasted the code exactly from the [docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js), I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword is a proposed es7 feature, you need to add babel's `stage-0` preset: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-stage-0

Alternatively you can just do the business after your class:

```
class RouteCSSTransitionGroup extends React.Component {
...
}

RouteCSSTransitionGroup.contextTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: thanks man, I've tried both your solutions but now I have another Unexpected token on `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup {...props}>`, this time the arrow points on the open tag `<` of ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Comment: @LucaMormile sounds like your jsx transformation is not working - you need the es2015 and react preset also https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/

Comment: Also just my opinion but webpack is much better than browserify (and about 15x faster at incrementally compiling)

Comment: I'll surely see for webpack, if you let me I'd like to show my CLI script to compile: browserify main.jsx -o public/js/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets stage-0  [ es2015 react ] ]

Comment: Looks ok but I'm not a browserify expert, stage 0 should go inside the square brackets i.e. `--presets [ stage-0 es2015 react ]`. Also I assume you installed the other presets i.e. `npm i babel-preset-react babel-preset-react`. There was an issue when I last tried getting stage-0 to work with those other presets though, but the react and es2015 ones should work fine together

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev babel-loader

npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react

npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-stage-1 babel-preset-stage-2 babel-preset-stage-3

and:

```
 query:{
        presets:['es2015','react','stage-0','stage-1','stage-2','stage-3']
      }
```